# socket - 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Good afternoon, I'm starting with the sockets tool in python and I'm creating a basic server.
However, it throws me an error:
`'str' object can not be interpreted as an integer`

Now modify the code several times but the error keeps appearing.
the last change was the `client.sendto (msg.encode ('utf-8'))`

This is my code:

server:

```
import socket

ip = "0.0.0.0"
puerto = 8081
dataConection = (ip,puerto)
conexionesMaximas = 10

socketServidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketServidor.bind(dataConection)
socketServidor.listen(conexionesMaximas)

print("Esperando conexiones en: ",ip,puerto)
cliente,direccion = socketServidor.accept()
print("Conexion establecida con: ",direccion[0],direccion[1])

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024)
    print(datos)
    modificado,severAdress = cliente.recvfrom(datos.decode('utf-8'))
    if modificado == "exit":
        cliente.send("exit")
    print("Recibido",data)
    cliente.sendall("---Recibido---")
print("Conexion cerrada")
socketServidor.close()
```

client:

```
import socket

ipServidor = "192.168.6.1"
puertoServidor = 8081

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((ipServidor,puertoServidor))
print("conectado con: ",ipServidor,puertoServidor)

while True:
    msg = input(">: ")
    cliente.sendto(msg.encode("utf-8"),(ipServidor,puertoServidor))
    respuesta = cliente.recv(4096)
    print(respuesta)
    if respuesta == "exit":
        break;

print("----conexion cerrada----")
cliente.close()
```

this is the line error:

```
Esperando conexiones en:  0.0.0.0 8081
Conexion establecida con:  192.168.8.3 49774
b'k'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\server.py", line 19, in <module>
    modificado,severAdress = cliente.recvfrom(datos.decode('utf-8'))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please show the error traceback.  What line has the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of errors, but mainly there is no need to use `sendto` and `recvfrom` on a connected socket.  Below code is written to run both client and server on the same computer:

**server.py**

```
import socket

ip = ""
puerto = 8081
dataConection = (ip,puerto)
conexionesMaximas = 10

socketServidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketServidor.bind(dataConection)
socketServidor.listen(conexionesMaximas)

print("Esperando conexiones en: ",ip,puerto)
cliente,direccion = socketServidor.accept()
print("Conexion establecida con: ",direccion[0],direccion[1])

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(datos)
    if datos == "exit":
        cliente.sendall("exit".encode())
        break
    print("Recibido",datos)
    cliente.sendall("---Recibido---".encode())
print("Conexion cerrada")
socketServidor.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

ipServidor = "localhost"
puertoServidor = 8081

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((ipServidor,puertoServidor))
print("conectado con: ",ipServidor,puertoServidor)

while True:
    msg = input(">: ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(4096).decode()
    print(respuesta)
    if respuesta == "exit":
        break

print("----conexion cerrada----")
cliente.close()
```

Note that `recv(1024)` on a TCP socket is a byte stream with no message boundaries, so there is no guarantee you'll receive all bytes of a message without implementing an additional protocol.  For example, sending the length of the message before the message, or for string-oriented messages like this, reading until a new line character is received.  for short strings like this, you may never see an issue, or would only see the issue when the network is very busy or unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `recvfrom` with an argument of the incorrect type. The `socket.recvfrom` method accepts a *buffer size* as its first argument, which specifies the maximum number of bytes to receive. You are giving it a string, the decoded bytes in `datos`.

If you are certain that `datos` contains an integer in string form, you can convert it to an integer by simply calling: `cliente.recvfrom(int(datos.decode('utf-8')))`.